# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable, I can't understand the issue

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm a beginner at programming and I'm making a program that takes input text and autocorrect it. the code seems fine for small sentences but when i paste a paragraph. the code return with this error.

```
# this a program that accepts input from the user and returns
#the number of words and the auto-correct the use

# step1: taking input from user (string) 
docx = input('enter the letter')

#step2: extract words from sentence
str_list = docx.split()
str_list = [x.lower() for x in str_list]

#step3: autocorrect part

# loading json file
import json
data = json.load(open('C:/Users/OMAIR salah/Desktop/autocorrect/words_dictionary2.json'))

# importing the comparing library
from difflib import get_close_matches

# the loop ( change the words if the spelling is wrong)
for i in range(0,len(str_list)):
    searcher = data.get(str_list[i][0])
    if str_list[i] in searcher :
        pass
    else:
        if len(get_close_matches(str_list[i],data.values())) > 0 :
            str_list[i] = get_close_matches(str_list[i],data.values()[0]
        else:
            print(f'the word {str_list[i]} does not exist')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Posting the exact line on which you got the error would be helpful to let us figure out where the issue lies. Copy the entire traceback and paste it here.

Comment: Please add the entire error message. Also add the text you tried to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
# the loop ( change the words if the spelling is wrong)
for i in range(0,len(str_list)):
    searcher = data.get(str_list[i][0])
    if str_list[i] in searcher :
```

The `.get()` method returns `None` when the requested key is not found.  So in this case `searcher` is `None`.  Then you try to use the `in` operator, which does its job by iteration, but you can't iterate over `None`, hence the error.

One possible fix is to supply an extra argument to `.get()` to specify a default value that should be returned, instead of `None`, when the requested key is not found:

```
# assign an empty list to searcher if the key is not found
searcher = data.get(str_list[i][0], [])
```